# How to get values of table from another table in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

pretty sure its the lack of sleep and the fact i've run out of coffee but i'm really struggling to get this in my head.

So I have 2 tables, Conversations which my model is:

```
public class Conversation
{
    [Key]
    public int ConversationId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; } = new Collection<Message>();
}
```

and Messages :

```
public class Message
{
    [Key]
    public int MessageId { get; set; }

    public string MessageContent { get; set; }

    public string Sender { get; set; }

    public string Receiver { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

now in my controller method I am trying to pull in all messages if they contain the passed in users in the method

e.g

```
    [Route("GetAllUserConversations")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<List<Conversation>> GetAllUserConversations(string receiverEmail, string senderEmail)
    {
        var conversation = _dbContext.Conversations
        .Include(m => m.Messages)
        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Messages.Where(x => x.Receiver == receiverEmail) && x.Messages.Where(y => y.Sender == senderEmail);

        return conversation;
    }
```

so if receiverEmail AND SenderEmail are present in the message then I want to pull in that message.

an example of the message I am trying to get is:

[image]

thanks!

Comment: Please specify your problem

Comment: I want all messages that have the Sender and Receiver properties equal to the passed in arguments

Comment: try if this query is translated to sql correctly : `var conversations = _dbContext.Conversations.Include(m => m.Messages).Where(x => x.Messages.Any(x => x.Receiver == receiverEmail && x.Sender == senderEmail)).ToListAsync();`

Comment: hmmm that doesnt seem to work, i have updated my question with a screen shot of the message I am trying to pull in

Comment: so you don't need conversations just messages?

Comment: Who says that there is only one conversation between this Sender email and receiver email? If they had several conversations, don't you want them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this;

```
var conversation = _dbContext.Conversations
                  .Include(m => m.Messages.Where(x => x.Receiver == receiverEmail && x => x.Sender == senderEmail))                  
                  .SingleOrDefault();
```

But I think you should consider your data model over again. You will experience some difficulties such as this one you encountered a lot if you use this model. It would be better with this for instance:

```
- User
--- Id
--- Email
--- Name    

- Conversation
--- Id
--- Name
--- List<ConversationMember> Members    
--- List<Message> Messages 

- ConversationMember
--- Id
--- ConversationId
--- UserId    

- Message
--- Id
--- ConversationId
--- SenderMemberId
```

---

```
var conversation = _dbContext.Conversations
                  .Include(cnv => cnv.Members)                  
                  .Include(cnv => cnv.Messages)
                  .SingleOrDefault(cnv.Members.Any(mmb => mmb.UserId == userId1 || mmb.UserId == userId2));
```